# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32'). I've already fill the input Nans with mode

Tags: python

```
x=train.drop(['PerStatus'],axis=1)
y=train['PerStatus']
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)
x_train_std=x_train
x_test_std=x_test
std=StandardScaler()
x_train_std=std.fit_transform(x_train_std)
x_test_std=std.fit_transform(x_test_std)

# RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

Furthermore I used .dtypes to check is there any missing values but apparently there isn't and I also print it.

Comment: What is the question, exactly, if there are no missing values and you've replaced NaNs already?

Comment: It still ran out of this "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')."

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using values that are exponentially large?
In the unlikely case that you are, one problem is that you are feeding the Random Forest with x_train instead of x_train_std, which is the scaled one and should be used instead. Check if that does anything

Comment: Yup, nothing has changed. Or could we exchange email. Cause I really need help. :((

Comment: Dont worry I will be active here.
Could you post the traceback of the error message? (the full error message)

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-f9b9ac5d7793> in <module>()
     11 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
     12 rf = RandomForestClassifier()
---> 13 rf.fit(x_train,y_train)

Comment: 2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     58                     msg_err.format
     59                     (type_err,
---> 60                      msg_dtype if msg_dtype is not None else X.dtype)
     61             )
     62     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

Comment: does your input data have 'object' datatypes (i.e. strings)? A Random Forest Classifier will only take float values, so if the string is one of the features, you could encode it.
If you can confirm your input has strings, I would write a full answer below

Comment: My x_train.dtypes showed  it's dtype: object and the colmuns are float64 or int64

Comment: Like these yyyy           int64
PerNo          int64
sex          float64
工作分類         float64
職等           float64
廠區代碼         float64
管理層級         float64